# How to combine multiple trained models of Tensorflow API

Tags: python, graph, tensorflow, models, object-detection

I would like to know how to combine multiple models in tensorflow API, for example, I would like to combine the outputs from pre-trained COCO model and also from the trained OXFORD Pet data. Is there any way to combine them and try to get both the result in the same session of tensorflow?

When I try to get the graph of both the models in a session as below, I am failing here:

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

detection_graph_PET = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph_PET.as_default():
  od_graph_def_PET = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT_PET, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph_PET = fid.read()
    od_graph_def_PET.ParseFromString(serialized_graph_PET)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def_PET, name='')
label_map_PET = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS_PET)
categories_PET = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map_PET, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES_PET, use_display_name=True)
category_index_PET = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories_PET)
return detection_graph, category_index, detection_graph_PET, category_index_PET
```

It throws some exception in terminal as below:

> od_graph_def_PET.ParseFromString(serialized_graph_PET)
>    google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

They work fine when they are run separately.

Is there a proper way to combine models?

Comment: "Combine" in what way?  You have two models that handle input in compatible formats and with output categories that correspond in some way.  Are you looking for a dual-channel fine tuning?

Comment: @Prune No no not like that, I am trying to give the same input to both the models and get two different output images and i want to check them simultaneously or even I can try to use the bounding boxes and class info of one model on to the other models output image. In this way, we have a combined output.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?